# How to filter a wav signal using IIR using fdatool?

Tags: matlab

I used fdatool to design an IIR filter , after the design i exported the co-ofcients `SOS` and `G`

then i used `Output1=filtfilt(SOS,G,wave);`, is that correct , because when it runs it take a very long time and when i plot the frequency and time response, no values appear ??

Comment: It could help if additionnal details were provided: what type of filter are you designing, what kind of wave is it, what is returned in Output1, ... For the computation time alone: it is possible that the type of filter you designed is of high order which will slow the computation, try a smoother filter which should be of lower order.

Answer (score 2):

The `filtfilt` function is expecting the numerator and denominator coefficient vectors (B and A, respectively) of the transfer function as the first two arguments. you can use the SOS2TF function to convert the second order sections into these coeffectient vectors:

```
[B,A] = sos2tf(SOS,G);
```

Then you can use the filtfilt function:

```
Output = filtfilt(B,A,wave);
```

While this would work, I would watch out when using high order systems; breaking up a high order filter into many cascaded low order filters is a good way to avoid coefficient error.