# Wrong data scaling while using fdatool

Tags: matlab, filtering

I have the same problem that was presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329141/how-to-filter-a-wav-signal-using-iir-using-fdatool), but it's solution doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

I have sound (wav) data with strong fundamental frequency (225 Hz, sample rate 96 000, amplitude ca. 0.2) and I want to design passband filter to eliminate just the f0. Using `fdatool` I have designed desired passband filter (from 220 to 230 Hz, -10 dB at 210 and 240 Hz) and exported `SOS` and `G`.

- If I use `sosfilt`, the data are OK, but not scaled correctly (amplitudes at `e30` or higher).
- If I use `sos2tf` and then `filt` or `filtfilt`, the data are still OK, but still incorrectly scaled (amplitudes at `e-19`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your code example? it would to make clear what you have tried, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how can I provide you with more code. I've used described procedure and it wasn't a part of any more complex function, therefore there is no more or wider code.

Comment: A code example would be a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, you have listed commands and described the inputs. That does not let someone pick up the question see the issue and then post a correct solution. This makes it a more time consuming question to answer.   This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30838907/97073)   includes lines of code rather than just listing functions, the answer also includes executable code. I was trying to guide the question so it may get a better response.